# How to make the second table appears after selecting a row in the first table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a new ASP.NET developer and trying to develop two dynamic tables where the user can add a new row directly in the first table, when he finished adding it, he will be able to select it to open the second table underneath the first table. I have a problem now in selecting on the rows in the first table in order to show the second table. **So how to get it?**

FYI, I have the following database design:

```
Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, Description
Question Table: QuestionID, Question, QuestionOrder, AnswerExplanation
QuestionImage Table: ID, QuestionID, URL
Answer Table: AnswerID, Answer
QuizContent Table: ID, QuizID, QuestionID, AnswerID
```

In addition, the first table will be for inserting the questions and the second table will be for inserting the answers. So how I can select a question to show the second table and being able to insert the answers for that question.

ASP.NET Code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Table ID="questionsList" runat="server" Width="70%" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0"
                    style="border:2px solid #003366; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold;">
                    <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                        <asp:TableHeaderCell>ID</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                        <asp:TableHeaderCell>Question</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                        <asp:TableHeaderCell>Question Order</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                        <asp:TableHeaderCell>Answer Explanation</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
        </asp:Table>

        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" Width="70%" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="0" 
                    style="border:2px solid #003366;">
            <asp:TableFooterRow>
                <asp:TableCell>Add</asp:TableCell>

                <asp:TableCell >
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestion" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    <%--For the txtQuestion TextBox Control--%>
                    <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender1" runat="server"
                                    TargetControlID="txtQuestion" WatermarkText="Type the Question here"
                                    WatermarkCssClass="watermarked">
                    </ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                </asp:TableCell>

                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestionOrder" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    <%--For the txtQuestionOrder TextBox Control--%>
                    <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender2" runat="server"
                                    TargetControlID="txtQuestionOrder" WatermarkText="Type the Question Order here"
                                    WatermarkCssClass="watermarked">
                    </ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                </asp:TableCell>

                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAnswerExplanation" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    <%--For the txtAnswerExplanation TextBox Control--%>
                    <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender3" runat="server"
                                    TargetControlID="txtAnswerExplanation" WatermarkText="Type the Answer Explanation here"
                                    WatermarkCssClass="watermarked">
                    </ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                </asp:TableCell>

                <asp:TableCell>
                    <span style="margin:3px 10px 0px 0px;">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="addButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/tick_small.png" OnClick="addQuestion" />
                    </span>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableFooterRow>
        </asp:Table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code-Behind:

```
public void fill_Questions()
    {

        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QuizSysDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Question";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

        Table table = (Table)UpdatePanel1.FindControl("questionsList");
        try
        {
            table.Rows.Clear();
            //open the connection
            conn.Open();
            //filling the dataset with the data
            sda.Fill(ds);
            //close the connection
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            table.Rows.Clear();
        }


        //Loading the data into the table
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            int rowsNum = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < rowsNum; i++) 
            {
                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                table.Rows.Add(row);

                for (int colCount = 0; colCount < 5; colCount++)
                {
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);

                    if (colCount == 0)
                    {
                        //int n = i + 1;
                        cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["QuestionID"].ToString()));
                    }
                    else if (colCount == 1)
                    {
                        cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Question"].ToString()));
                    }
                    else if (colCount == 2)
                    {
                        cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["QuestionOrder"].ToString()));
                    }
                    else if (colCount == 3)
                    {
                        cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["AnswerExplanation"].ToString()));
                    }
                    else if (colCount == 4)
                    {
                        ImageButton deleteButton = new ImageButton();
                        deleteButton.ImageUrl = "Images/DeleteRed.png";
                        deleteButton.ID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["QuestionID"].ToString() + "_" + i;
                        deleteButton.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(deleteQuestion);
                        cell.Controls.Add(deleteButton);

                    }
                } //End for loop
            }//End OUTER for loop

        }//End if statement

    }


    //For deleting question
    public void deleteQuestion(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        string id = ((ImageButton)sender).ID.ToString().Split('_')[0];
        try 
        {
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QuizSysDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            string deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM Question WHERE QuestionID = @id";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteQuery,conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            fill_Questions();
        }
        catch(SqlException se){}

        UpdatePanel1.Update();

    }


    //For adding questions
    public void addQuestion(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        try 
        {
            TextBox txtQuestion = (TextBox)UpdatePanel1.FindControl("txtQuestion");
            TextBox txtQuestionOrder = (TextBox)UpdatePanel1.FindControl("txtQuestionOrder");
            TextBox txtAnswerExplanation = (TextBox)UpdatePanel1.FindControl("txtAnswerExplanation");

            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QuizSysDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Question (Question, QuestionOrder, AnswerExplanation) VALUES (@Question, @QuestionOrder, @AnswerExplanation)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery,conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question", txtQuestion.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionOrder", txtQuestionOrder.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AnswerExplanation", txtAnswerExplanation.Text);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            fill_Questions();
        }
        catch(SqlException se){}
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I created two tables for the Answers as I did for the questions. Now, **How Am I gonna be able to show these table after selecting one question?**

ASP.NET code:

```
<div align="center">
    <h3>Answers List</h3>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Table ID="answersList" runat="server" Width="70%" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0"
                    style="border:2px solid #003366; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold;">
                    <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                        <asp:TableHeaderCell>Answer</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
        </asp:Table>

        <asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="server" Width="70%" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="0" 
                    style="border:2px solid #003366;">
            <asp:TableFooterRow>
                <asp:TableCell>Add</asp:TableCell>

                <asp:TableCell >
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAnswer" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    <%--For the txtQuestion TextBox Control--%>
                    <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender4" runat="server"
                                    TargetControlID="txtAnswer" WatermarkText="Type the Answer here"
                                    WatermarkCssClass="watermarked">
                    </ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                </asp:TableCell>

                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="isCorrectCheckBox" runat="server" />
                </asp:TableCell>

                <asp:TableCell>
                    <span style="margin:3px 10px 0px 0px;">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ToolTip="Add" ImageUrl="Images/tick_small.png" OnClick="addAnswer" />
                    </span>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableFooterRow>
        </asp:Table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel> 
    </div>
```

Comment: why don't you use GridView and DetailsView?

Comment: is it possible to do what I want and explained above very easily with the GridView? Also, it will be a waste of time now to repeat what I did from zero. What do you think?

Comment: Yes I think GridView is the best option. But I haven't used asp:Table before to work with data.